# How to nest quotes in bash commands

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I want to test the result of this command:

```
dmesg | grep "Firmware patch 1563"
```

Therefore, I try to write something like this:

```
if [ "`dmesg | grep "Firmware patch 1563`" == "" ]
```

But it doesn't work. How should I rewrite this command?

Comment: The answers are better ways of doing this, but your direct problem is that you're not nesting the quotes correctly - it needs to be `1563"\`"` (two double quotes). Bash handles nesting quotes just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) directly:

```
if $(dmesg | grep -q "Firmware patch 1563"); then
  # Do something here
fi
```

Or a better way, use commands directly like [l0b0's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159771/38906).

Comment: Don't need (or want) command substitution in an `if` command.

Comment: The use of command substitution is unnecessary here, see the other A, you can do this directly in the if statement. It's more performant and easier to read.

Comment: Updated men, I saw l0b0's answer when I was editing mine.

Answer (score 7):

You can test the result of a command directly:

```
if dmesg | grep -q "Firmware patch 1563"
```

If you need to check whether the output of a pipe is empty, [use `$()` for command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) and nest your [quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) as you would with a free-standing command:

```
if [ -z "$(my_command | other_command "some argument")" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote should work. It doesn't because you forgot a quote. It should be:

```
if [ "`dmesg | grep "Firmware patch 1563"`" == "" ]
```

Note the extra `"` after `1563`. With that being said, I think [the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159771/38906) gives you better ways to achieve what you want to do.